# How to avoid conflicts in I/O physical addresses in Linux for PC/104?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, memory-address

I am new to using PC/104 stack running Ubuntu 16.04
PC/104 is a single board where you can stack multiple peripheral boards.
Many of these peripheral boards have configurable bases address that can is determined by the order of the jumppers insert. (eg. Sensoray's Model 526, PEAK's PCAN-PC/104-Plus Quad)

My PC/104 will have many of these peripheral boards and I am suppose to make sure their memory mapped I/O addresses don't clash.

How do I check which address is already taken and is there a maximum limit to the I/O space that I can set the peripheral boards to?

Comment: *"How do I check which address is already taken...?"* -- There's always the old-fashioned way of manual inspection, and using pen & paper to construct a memory map.

Comment: It's usually done at the time of prototyping the resulting product. I.o.w. a designer **knows** this in advance and places devices to avoid resource clashing.

Comment: So there is no way to programmatically (software or shell code) determine the memory map usage?

Comment: You are using hardware that is not self-identifying. So there is no reliable method by software. That's why such ISA/EISA expansion boards are not used in modern PCs, which are now plug-n-play, e.g. PCI/PCIe.